# Prevent functional component from overriding data with default values

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a functional component which is a wrapper for other functional components. 
I'm receiving an object from the context which contains some data that I'd like to pass down as props after i do some date formatting on it. 
Like so:

```
<MyComponent
schema={mtaSchema}
monthInitVal={object.month}
yearInitVal={object.year}
/>
```

```
let object = { month: '', year: '' };

  function getDateInitialValues(dateOfPurchase) {
    return {
      month: dateOfPurchase.format('M'),
      year: dateOfPurchase.format('YYYY'),
    };
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (updatesCar.purchaseDate) {
      object = getDateInitialValues(
        moment(updatesCar.purchaseDate, 'DD-MMM-YYYY'),
      );
    }
  }, [updatesCar.purchaseDate]);
```

The intended functionality is: I go on to the page - i.e the page which contains the above component - which also happens to be a form. I'm happy with the initial values of `''` so that bit is OK.

I would expect those default values to be be updated after the relevant user interaction(which is a user event that happens a bit further down the line) which *they do*.

The problem is that due to this entire component being a functional component it re-renders several times which then resets back my `monthInitVal` and `yearInitVal` to their original state of `''` since we never go into the `useEffect` which updates to what they need to be the second time... Therefore i'm left with a `''` set of options for my comp :-(

Any ideas on how to go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use the [state hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). Your `let object = { month: '', year: '' };`
should be kept in a state hook and this way get it to survive the re-renders

```
 const [month, setMonth] = useState(0);
 const [year, setYear] = useState(0);

function getDateInitialValues(dateOfPurchase) {
....
```